# In pandas how to fetch only 2nd column after splitting the values by double quotes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Data looks like this:
[image]

How can I fetch only the values which are in 2nd double quotes?

I want the output to be like this:
[image]

This is code I tried but it is not giving the expected results.

```
refunds['REFUND_INFO'] = refunds['REFUND_INFO'].str.split('"',expand=True).get[1]
```

Comment: please copy and paste your dataframe. We need it to help you, thanks!

Comment: `refunds['REFUND_INFO'].str.split('"',expand=True)[1]` ?

Comment: why not convert it to the dictionary and fetch the "reason" key?